# Reprojecting xyz rgb file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, xyz, rgb

I am trying to reproject an XYZ RGB point cloud file that I got from a drone mapping software. It is now in WGS84 and I want it in euref32(UTM) or just a local metric system so i can import it Into an CAD program. There is an option to remove the RGB values, but then I would lose the colors in my model.

How can i do this without losing the RGB values?

I have tried the reprojecting function in QGIS and only gets error.
This is the error I get:

```
ERROR 1: Ungridded dataset: At line 3, change of Y direction
```

Here is an sample from my XYZ RGB file:

-117.259861 32.802178 -0.511405 110 114 121
-117.259718 32.802270 4.390094 116 105 84
-117.259853 32.802182 -0.488624 114 115 118
-117.259799 32.802216 1.245612 63 73 62
-117.259711 32.802274 4.404747 115 105 83
-117.259772 32.802232 1.830184 56 81 42
-117.259749 32.802247 2.655255 77 89 55
-117.259745 32.802249 2.827860 130 124 98
[image]

Comment: Add a few lines of your XYZ file or a link to a small sample.

Comment: ... and perhaps screenshots of the warp dialogue and the error message.

Comment: Your input file is not a regular raster, so you need to import it as vector data.

Comment: It will not import as an vector. But i can import it as an table.

Comment: Are you importing it using Add Delimeted Text option?
 https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77302/adding-xy-data-on-qgis

Comment: Why does it "not import as an vector"?