# QGIS 2.18: Import Result Table of a query into QGIS as pointlayer

Tags: qgis, postgis, point, import, qgis-2.18

I have a query which outputs a table with an unique nodeID and x-,y-coordinates.

How can I import this query result table into qgis as an point-layer?

I have tried it with the DB-Manager (see below) and by WFS. But both hasn't worked out for me although I was able to specify a query.

[image]

The following shows you the SQL query I am running to get my result query table which I want to import in QGIS as point-layer:

```
SELECT "from" AS nodeID,
       st_x AS x,
       st_y AS y,
       priority AS type
FROM (SELECT "from",
             st_x(st_pointn(geom,1)),
             st_y(st_pointn(geom,1)) 
      FROM public.graph
      UNION
      SELECT "to",
             st_x(st_pointn(geom,st_npoints(geom))), 
             st_y(st_pointn(geom,st_npoints(geom))) 
      FROM public.graph
      ORDER BY "from") AS nodes
INNER JOIN junctions on nodes."from" = id
```

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with this process to fully answer but I think you need to add a geometry column to your query so you end with spatial data

Comment: but I do have the x-/y-coordinates though. I think this must be enough for importing it as a point-layer to qgis.

Comment: what you probably rather want is using `ST_StartPoint` & `ST_EndPoint` instead of extracting the coordinates from the first and last vertex (from which you, btw., would only need to create a `ST_MakePoint`). please copy your query as code formatted text into the question body instead of an image! it'seasier to parse for anybody trying to help, and also complete...

Comment: @ThingumaBob I have added the query to the question body. Thank you for your suggestion. But how can I import the result of the query to qgis as a point-layer?

Comment: This question could help you : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77302/adding-xy-data-on-qgis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (I've deducted some data provenance), and I've assigned as CRS the WGS84, EPSG: 4326 (I let you correct this if wrong) :

```
SELECT nodes.nodeID,
       junctions.priority AS type,
       nodes.geom
FROM (SELECT "from" AS nodeID,
             ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(st_x(st_pointn(geom,1)), st_y(st_pointn(geom,1))), 4326) AS geom
      FROM public.graph
      UNION ALL
      SELECT "to" AS nodeID,
             ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(st_x(st_pointn(geom,st_npoints(geom))), st_y(st_pointn(geom,st_npoints(geom)))), 4326) AS geom
      FROM public.graph) AS nodes
INNER JOIN public.junctions ON nodes.nodeID = junctions.id
```