# Adding own data - QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm using QGIS and I want to map some specific shops in a city. I have collected X and Y coordinates and names so now I would like to add as a layer and then connect with a map.

Does anyone know how to add own collected data?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: See this tutorial on how to [edit/digitize](https://www.qgistutorials.com/ru/docs/3/digitizing_basics.html) data, maybe jump to section 6

Comment: Formulate the question precisely is the tricky stuff, thank you for the info I will do it for the next time.

Comment: If you have your own X and Y already check out: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77302/adding-xy-data-on-qgis